# Cannot restore data from pg_dump due to blank strings being treated as nonexistant data

Tags: postgresql, docker, restore, database-backups

I have a database currently on a PostgreSQL 9.3.9 server that I am backing up with pgdump in the simplest possible fashion, eg `pg_dump orb > mar_9_2018.db`.

One of those tables (linktags) has the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE linktags (
    linktagid integer NOT NULL,
    linkid integer,
    tagval character varying(1000)
);
```

When attempting to restore the database on PostgreSQL 11.2 via

`cat mar_9_2018.db | docker exec -i pg-docker psql -U postgres`

(docker container restore) the table returns empty because of the following error -

```
ERROR:  missing data for column "tagval"
CONTEXT:  COPY linktags, line 737: "1185    9325"
 setval
```

I checked the db file and found that there are missing tabs where I would expect some sort of information, and clearly the restore process does as well.

[image: demonstration of tabs missing with regular expressions]

I also verified that the value in the database is a blank string.

So -

- Is there an idiomatic method to backup and restore a postgres database I am missing?
- Is my version old enough that this version of pg_dump should have some special considerations?
  Am I just restoring this wrong?

Edit: 
I did some further research and found that I was incorrect in the original checking of NULLs, it was instead blank strings that are causing the issue.

If I make an example table with null strings and then blank strings, I can see the NULLs get a newline but the blank does not [image: null values showing a \n and blanks showing no \n]

Comment: I verified that pg_dump in version 10 has the same behavior.

Comment: On a 9.5 postgres installation pg_dump defaults to use a `COPY` statement with tab separated values of `\N` for any fields containing NULL values.

Comment: thank you @clamp I was mistaken, the issue arises only with blank strings, not with null values. I have updated the question with additional examples.

Comment: The blanks get a newline as well, otherwise 3 and 4 would be on the same line.

Comment: Also if you check the dump in an editor or using `cat -T` , you should see tabs in line 3 and 4.

Comment: Great points all that I cant deny (once I used cat -T thank you for that) - so what else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you modifying the dump in any way before you try to reload it? E.g. opening in an editor with a setting that removes trailing whitespace, or perhaps a git setting ?

Comment: Great ideas, I will see if I get any luck tonight :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) has an option to use `INSERT` instead of `COPY`

```
pg_dump -d db_name --inserts
```

as the manual warns, it might make restoration slow (and much larger dump file). Even in case of some inconsistencies tables will be filled with valid rows.

Another problem is with empty tables, `pg_dump` generates empty copy statement like:

```
COPY config (key, value) FROM stdin;
\.
```

in this case you'll be getting errors on reimport like:

```
 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type smallint: "  "
CONTEXT:  COPY config, line 1, column group: "  "
```

which doesn't happen with `--insert` option (no insert statement is generated).

Comment: I dont have the original stuff to test anymore, but that looks about right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using inserts slows down restoration a lot. I tested it for quite the small database and I had to cancel the import after 5 minutes without finishing.

However, you can use the `--quote-all-identifiers` flag (see the [pg_dump documentation for further information](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)) to enclose empty strings in quotes.
This way the copy command works as expected with empty strings.